# Microsoft Azure Server Error

Tags: azure-web-app-service

i am trying to deploy my cakephp 3.0 application in microsoft azure. But it shows server error 500. I have tried every method include htaccess mod rewrite but not able to solve this error. Please Help

Thank you

Comment: You're going to have to give some more details.

Comment: Actually i have created a video streaming project in cakephp 3.0 in my local machine and now i want to deploy it in microsoft azure web app. but after uploading my complete project in that environment and run. it shows server error and Error code 500.

Comment: too bad people down-voted you, lets see have you added the right http handlers with your code.

Comment: Sir i did not check yet. But yes there must be an error because of this handler. and one thing when i deploy my repository direct from bitbucket to microsoft azure it escapes Vendor Folder why ??

thank you for your kind reply

Comment: Is this an issue with the Composer Extension? I wrote that extension and would love to fix any issues you run into. please file a bug: http://github.com/SyntaxC4-MSFT/ComposerExtension

Answer (score 1):

Azure Web App doesn't support the use of htaccess, if you use a tool such as http://htaccesstowebconfig.com to paste in your htaccess file and it will provide you with the web.config file that is required for IIS.

If you would like to vote on Web App providing support for .htaccess you can add your feedback on [uservoice](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/7774113-support-htaccess-files-for-php)